# How do I sum irregular data ranges in excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

So I have an irregular range of data, sometimes it has 5 rows, 4 rows, 10 rows, etc. and I need to make the sum of each *group* of rows.

This would be a problem when I have tons of row groups I need to sum, it'll be tedious manually.

here's the image of what I want to do:
[image: here's the image of what I want to do]

the D8 cell would countain the sum of C1:C7, and D14 cell would contain the sum of C9:C13, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in D2 and copy down:

```
=IF(A2<>"",SUM($C$1:$C2)-SUM($D$1:$D1),"")
```

If basically sums everything in column C from the first value to the current row and subtracts that which has already been summed.

So in D8 it would sum C1:C8 and subtract the sum of D1:D7 which is `0`.  Then in D14 it would sum C1:C14 and subtract what is in D8 to get the correct value.

Comment: This is an absolutely brilliant solution! Thanks!